# Detect disconnected Graph components efficiently?

Tags: java, graph-theory

I have the following which searches my graph to see if a vertex is reachable from the first vertex, which everything should be connected to. I do this to ensure there are no disconnected parts.

Unfortunately it is very slow.

Is there something I could do or store to optimize this?

I want to learn about graphs and generated cities so Im not using a real graph library.

```
private void removeDisconnectedSquares()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < getNumXNodes(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < getNumYNodes(); ++j)
        {
            //removeDisconnectedSquare(i, j);
            visitedNodes.clear();
            if(!isNodeReachableFrom(getNodeAt(i, j), getNodeAt(0, 0)))
            {
                removeVertex(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isNodeReachableFrom(GraphNode node, GraphNode target)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(visitedNodes.contains(node))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        visitedNodes.add(node);
    }

    if(node == target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(node.contains(target))
    {
        return true;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < node.getSize(); ++i)
    {
        if(isNodeReachableFrom(node.at(i), target))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This seems to fit [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) more than SO. You should probably try asking there.

Comment: I'd say it belongs here because he's sort of asking for how to find disconnected components of his graph quickly.

Comment: I find this statement ("I want to learn about graphs and generated cities so Im not using a real graph library.") to be rather counter-intuitive.  Studying an open-source graph library would be a good way to accomplish your goal of learning more about graphs.  For example, the source to an industrial-strength graph library would likely answer this question.

Comment: Also, what kind of data container is visited nodes?  If it is a dynamic array or list, changing to a map/set might improve your performance scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is detect disconnected vertices. What you should do is something along the lines of:

```
private ArrayList<GraphNode> getDisconnectedSet(ArrayList<GraphNode> allNodes, GraphNode target)
{
    if(!allNodes.contains(target))
        return;

    allNodes.remove(target);

    for(Edge e : edges) // Need to edit to iterate through connected nodes
        getDisconnectedSet(allNodes, e.otherSide);
}
```

Then you call getDisconnectedSet with a list of all the nodes and after it returns the list only contains the disconnected nodes.

Comment: The problem is I dont have a connected node list, both the connected and disconnected are in the same array.

Comment: Yes, but at each node you have a list of which nodes are directly connected to that node. Maybe my edit is a little more clear (or maybe less :P)